# Uninitialized constant in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to work through [this](https://www.codecademy.com/final_project/learn-ruby) tutorial for Ruby, on CodeAcademy. The following code is giving me the error

"uninitialized constant List::Task (NameError)
    from to_do.rb:2:in main"

I understand that this may be related to the List class not being able to access the Task class, but I can't see where this would be breaking down? The code is below.

```
   #list class

   class List
    attr_reader :all_tasks
    if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
      my_list = List.new
      puts 'You have created a new list'
      my_list.add(Task.new('Make Breakfast'))
      puts 'You have added a task to the Todo List'
   end

   def initialize
    @all_tasks = []
   end

 def add(task)
  @all_tasks << task
 end


 end


 #class task

 class Task
  attr_reader :description

  def task_item(desription)
   @new_item = description
  end
end
```

Comment: Any error trace?

Comment: `__FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME` . move this outside of the classes or call the method. when this evalutes to true, it will run and try to access Task which is yet to be defined. calling this method from `initialize` is a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you run this line

```
my_list.add(Task.new('Make Breakfast'))
```

`Task` hasn't been defined. That happens a few lines later.

Just swap the definitions of the `Task` and the `List` class.

Comment: Neither are defined list's initializer and `add`, which the OP will discover soon enough. This script must be extracted from List class and moved to the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

When you run that file from the command line as a script, order of declaration is important. If you move the declaration of Task above List you'll find that it will fix the error in question.